# execute scrapy runspider filename from php shell_exec() does not work

Tags: php, python, scrapy

How do I execute scrapy command line call via php language?
It works fine from the command shell when I write - scrapy runspider file.py, but the same cannot be executed using php command shell.

Comment: Some code would help. There should be an error in the web server error log.

Comment: $commandQuery = "scrapy runspider myspider.py";
$output=exec($commandQuery);

Comment: okay so I see the error in the log - it says 'scrapy: command not found'. But it works fine from the console

Comment: You will need to put the whole path to the scrapy command. Run whereis in the terminal to find where scrapy is. You may also need the full path for your python script.

Comment: That worked Thanks!